# Python guessing word game

Tags: python

I trying to convert my code using function. As this coding is not done yet but i manage to get the code running well. The only thing is every time i guess a letter, it reset my previous record. How to i store my previous guess result and continue add if the letter is guessed correctly?

```
import random

def chooseAword(wordList):
    correct_word = random.choice(wordList)
    return correct_word

#def spelltheword(word)


def guessAletter(guessedletter):
    word = guessedletter
    guess = input('Guess a letter: ')
    letter = ''.join(x if x in guess else '-' for x in word)

    if guess in word:
            print("So far you have: ", letter)
    else:
          print("So far you have: ", letter)

    return letter

def playAgame(wordList):
    word = chooseAword(wordList)
    for n in range(5):
        guessletter = guessAletter(word)

def main():
    wordList = ('python', 'csharp','java','oracle')
    playAgame(wordList)

main()
```

Comment: Can you post what your output looks like?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't reset your previous record: you *have* no previous record.  Every call to `guessAletter` very specifically puts a hyphen in any position that is *not* the currently guessed letter.

Yes, you return the word (which you named `letter`, for some reason) of hyphens and correct letters, but the calling program `playAgame` puts this into a local variable `guessletter` (another misleading name), and then never uses it again.

I have several suggestions:

1. Practice incremental programming.  Write a few lines of code to perform a trivial part of your program.  Debug them.  Do *not* continue until you know they do what you want, through testing several possibilities.  Then write a few more lines; repeat this process until your program works.
2. Use meaningful variable names.  `word` doesn't tell us much; we don't know whether this is the word we're supposed to guess, the current game progress you show the user, or something else.  At the worst, you use `guessedLetter` for something that is not a single letter, and is not a guess.
3. With the incremental programming, follow the status of your game state: this should be one value passed back and forth with your guess-and-check function.  You update it in that function, and print it in the guess-a-letter loop.